# Choices in speech recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm creating program similar to JARVIS from iron man based on speech recognition. I made one before using this:

```
case "Open facebook":
    JARVIS.Speak("Opening facebook");
    Process.Start("www.facebook.com");
    break;`
```

But now I want to create search option or even play. So far I made this for youtube search(one grammar and works great) but when I make two:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer JARVIS = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    string QEvent;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices artists = new Choices(new string[] { "bullet-for-my-valentine-curses", "black-veil-brides-saviour", "three-days-grace-wake-up" });
        Choices search = new Choices(new string[] { "bill-gates" });

        GrammarBuilder findServices = new GrammarBuilder("Play");
        findServices.Append(artists);
        GrammarBuilder google = new GrammarBuilder("Look");
        google.Append("for");
        google.Append(search);

        // Create a Grammar object from the GrammarBuilder and load it to the recognizer.
        Grammar servicesGrammar = new Grammar(findServices);
        Grammar lookingGrammar = new Grammar(google);
        _recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(servicesGrammar);
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(lookingGrammar);

        // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        // Configure the input to the speech recognizer.
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        JARVIS.Speak("Playing" + e.Result.Words[1].Text);
        Process.Start("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + e.Result.Words[1].Text);
        JARVIS.Speak("Searching" + e.Result.Words[2].Text + " " + e.Result.Words[3].Text);
    }

}
```

Where I say "Play" and the title of the songs and it opens Choices(artists)
for what I've said. And works with one grammar, but when I create two, like in the code above, and when I say something, program stops and shows the error.

```
{
    static class Program
    {

        // The main entry point for the application.
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); //this line show error
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I make multiple grammars, one for Google search, one for Wikipedia, and keep this one?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Which line is throwing the exception and exactly what type of exception are you getting?

Comment: When I debug the program, after I've created 2 grammars, one for youtube and one for wikipedia search, when I say something which is in the code, like "Play three days grace wake up" (After I've created 2 grammars) application stops to work and this part

`using...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  static class Program
  {

    // The main entry point for the application.
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1()); <---this one show error
    }
  }
}`

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the constructor of `Form1` does it get hit? If you then step through your code in the debugger, can you pinpoint the line that fails? Please also edit your question and append your code for the two-grammar version, since this is the one that's actually failing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to borrow Raymond Chen's Psychic Debugging Talents (tm) and say that your problem is here:

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(servicesGrammar);
_recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(lookingGrammar);
```

In particular, I suspect that the recognizer can have only one async grammar load at once.  If you change your code to

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(servicesGrammar);
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(lookingGrammar);
```

or put the second [LoadGrammarAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammarasync%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) call in a [onLoadGrammarCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammarcompleted%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) handler, your problems will go away.

But *seriously*, you need to include the error.